# Validation of empty fields in JavaScript and displaying text inside <p> tag

Tags: javascript

This is a guestbook validation which I am trying to make. The text in the `<p>` tag is not getting  changed and I don't know why. Could you help me to validate this form:

```js
function Frmvalidate() {
    var nmchk = document.forms["guestform1"]["name"].value;
    var cmntchk = document.forms["guestform1"]["comment"].value;
    if (nmchk == null || nmchk == "") {
        var namep = document.getElementById("namep");
        x.innerHTML = "name must be filled out";
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    if (cmntchk == null || cmntchk == "") {
        var cmntp = document.getElementById("cmntp");
        x.innerHTML = "comment must be filled out";
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
    var namep = document.getElementById("namep");
    x.innerHTML="name must be filled out";
```

you probably want

```
    var namep = document.getElementById("namep");
    namep.innerHTML="name must be filled out";
```

But when you execute the first `if else`, you quit the function, so you probably want to do this :

```
function Frmvalidate() {
    var nmchk=document.forms["guestform1"]["name"].value;
    var cmntchk=document.forms["guestform1"]["comment"].value;
    if (nmchk==""||nmchk==null) {
            var namep = document.getElementById("namep");
            namep.innerHTML="name must be filled out";
            return false;
    }
    if (cmntchk==""||cmntchk==null){
            var cmntp = document.getElementById("cmntp");
            cmntp.innerHTML="comment must be filled out";
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you dystroy! that worked! but still the form gets submitted with null data

Comment: You have selects ? I didn't think about other inputs than the text ones. I've updated.

Comment: i have 4 fields (ID,name,comment,date). i have assigned NOT NULL for name and comment. ID id the primary key and it has auto incrementation. date has php's date function.